# Model.IsValid is always false when I insert a datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have the following class:

```
public class Post
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Please fill in a valid date.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$", ErrorMessage="Fill in a valid date.")]
    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
}
```

and in my Edit action I have it like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Post post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(post);
    }
}
```

But my ModelState is always invalid. How come? How can I solve this?

I also posted here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1663783.aspx/1?MVC3+how+to+check+datetime+on+model+with+unobtrusive+javascript+.

Update: I found that there is indeed an error via:

```
ModelState.Values.Select(x => x.Errors);
```

But how can I find out how it gets there? And more important, how can I solve it?

Comment: have you checked Errors collection in ModelState?

Comment: Where can I find that? If I type ModelState.Errors it doesn't provide me something like it.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `if(ModelState.IsValid)`, then inspect the ModelState object with the debugger. You should be able sot see an error message with the associated entry in the ViewData dictionary...

Comment: What is the error message you foud about un your update?

Comment: The error I get is "Fill in a valid date."

Comment: Have you tried `[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Fill in a valid date"]` attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression does not work with the date that you enter. I would simply remove it since the `DateTime` struct will not be assigned if the date can't be parsed by the model binder.